# Send file - remove parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm navigating to a site like `/subsite` with a specific URL that hold the key parameter:

https://my.server.com/premiumSite?key=secretKey

or

https://my.server.com/premiumSite.html?key=secretKey

---

I'd like to determine if the `key` parameter is **"secretKey"**. If it is I'd like to send a file *(not redirect!)* called **premiumSite.html** to the user. If the key is something different I'd like to redirect the user to the **index.html** site to don't give the user access to my site.

The whole routine is working absolutely fine - but *(of course)* theres one problem:

The function `res.sendFile()` **(like I want it to be)** does not change the URL at all - what also effects the parameters.

> So how can I call `sendFile()` but also remove the "key" parameter from the URL at the same time (not using local js)?

---

```
let app = express();
app.use('/premiumSite(.html)?',function(req, res) {
  let isPremiumUser = req.query.key === "secretKey";  // check if URL parameters are matching
  if (isPremiumUser) res.sendFile("www/premiumSite.html", {root: __dirname});
  else res.redirect("www/index.html"); 
})
```

Comment: You can't change the URL from the server side without redirecting. This does include removing parameters. If you don't like the Params in the URL maybe attach them to the request as header or cookie?

Comment: Why not use a post or put and just have the secret key in the body?

Comment: You can use everything you like as URL, but you can ONLY change the URL with a redirect. So the only solution is to just accept that there is a parameter in your URL, redirect or embed it in the body or headers of the request.